# Fully destroy charts on ngDestroy method from Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, chart.js

This is my function where i draw the charts:

```
private drawCharts(charts) {
    this.charts = charts.map((chart, i) => {
        this.options.title.text = chart.title;
        const options = {
            type: this.type || 'bar',
            data: chart,
            options: this.options
        };
        return new Chart(`chart${i}`, options);
    });
}
```

and i try to destroy the charts when leave the page with ngOnDestroy method:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.charts && this.charts.length > 0) this.charts.forEach(chart => chart.destroy());
}
```

but it looks like that chart.destroy() doesn't work how i want or it doesn't destroy charts fully. The problem is that when i open the page with charts first time, Chart will create instances for my charts:

```
[
  {id: 0, ctx: null, canvas: null, config: {...}},
  {id: 1, ctx: null, canvas: null, config: {...}},
  {id: 2, ctx: null, canvas: null, config: {...}}
]
```

i'll leave the page and come back to page with charts, than Chart will create:

```
[
  {id: 3, ctx: null, canvas: null, config: {...}},
  {id: 4, ctx: null, canvas: null, config: {...}},
  {id: 5, ctx: null, canvas: null, config: {...}}
]
```

I need to fully destroy the charts every time when i leave this page and when i will open back the page the chart object instance should always start from 0 index as first time when i opened the page

Answer (score 0):

You've destroyed the charts, but not their context. Something is maintaining the count, either in your code or the Chart.js library.

If workarounds based on the order of these charts in your array are unreliable, then you could look into specifying the ID values on creation, or re-initialising the counter (possibly by recreating the object with that context).

Answer (score 0):

So, looks like it was a bad idea to use indexes of chart objects, i solved the problem in my case just when i start to create my own custom id's and use them.